# JOLT: modify each string in array

Tags: arrays, json, string, jolt, shift

I have some problem when tried to used JOLT for modify JSON.
I want to modify each string in array and only leave last 4 character.

Sample Input:

```
{
    "card" : [ "111111111", "222222222", "333333333", "444444444" ]
}
```

Expect Output:

```
{
    "card" : [ "***1111", "***2222", "***3333", "***4444" ]
}
```

Did i must to use shift operation?
Or maybe it possible can do without it?

I tried to do it without shift, but it dont work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following transformation spec presuming the components have variable length

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "card": {
        "*": "&1.&"
      },
      "@card": { // prepare to compute the sizes of each component of the array
        "*": "sz.&"
      }
    }
  },
  { // compute the sizes of each component
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "sz": {
        "*": "=size(@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  },
  { // combine each formed array under common nodes with key names 0,1,2...
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&"
      }
    }
  },
  { // extract the last 4 characters from each
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=substring(@(1,&[1]),5,@(1,&[0]))"
    }
  },
  { // prefix each with triple asterisks
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=concat('***',@(1,&))"
    }
  },
  { // accumulate all attributes under the common array, namely "card"
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "card"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thx for this solution, I will try it!
If i decide to use simple modify, like substring with the first two characters of elemennt - can that reduce the number of operations in jolt spec?

Comment: Hi @sizzz if the length of each components are fixed to 9, then we can reduce the number of specs.